# Clicking link in Chrome without it opening

Tags: google-chrome, script

It seems that many websites nowadays have some code, that when you first open the site and click anywhere on it, it opens a new tab, usually with some kind of advertisement which you manually have to close. Only then you can start interacting with the site. Is there any kind of keyboard combination or plug-in/setting that I could use to prevent that from happening?

Hope I explained it well enough for it to make sense..

Thanks

Comment: it would be pointless, basically it seems you are saying you want to browse single pages website with no, all websites have links, tabs so how would you browse a website if you can't open anything. if you goal is to block ads use an ad blocker. a better questions would be asking what your issue is than thinking of a solution that might not work and asking others how would that solution work

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like the kind of problem an ad-blocking addon/extension should prevent. Here are links to two of the most popular:

[uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en)

[AdBlock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)